# How to disabled button from child component ? Angular 2+

Tags: angular

I'm using  angular and I want to disable the button. I want to disable the button so that if you are not an answear or the next question you cannot go to the next step.

Example:

if you are not anwear on second question you can't go to third question.

The code is very large, but I will leave only a part here:

```
  mealPaging = {
    currentPage: 1,
    allPages: 10,
    isNextVisible: function (): boolean {
      return true;
    },
    nextStep: function () {
      this.currentPage += 1;
    },
    previousStep: function () {
      this.currentPage -= 1;
    },
    isPagerVisible: function () {
      return this.currentPage != 1;
    },
    getPercentage: function () {
      return Math.round((this.currentPage / this.allPages) * 100);
    }
  };

  objectToSendMeal = {
    perDay: 1 ,
    duration: 1,
    additionalSnack: '',
    timeForMeal: {
      hourFirstMeal: null,
      hourSecondMeal: null,
      hourThirdMeal: null,
    },
    whatOfterEat: {
      breakfast: new Date(),
      lounch: new Date(),
      dinner: new Date()
    },
    howMuchWaterDring: '',
    additionalSuplements: '',
    additionalSuplementIfYes: '',
    whenSleep:  null,
    whenEarly: null,
    whatEatForDinner: '',
    howMuchSnackPerDay: '',
    howMuchDringJuice: '',
    howMuchDrinkCoffee: '',
    goals: '',
    forbiddenFood: ''
  }

  arrOfSnack = [];
  existingIndex: any;
  favoritesFood = []; 
  now: Date = new Date();
  constructor( 
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() { 
  }
 
  

  nextPage(){
    this.mealPaging.nextStep();
  }

  receivedPage(page){ 
    if(page === 'next') 
      return this.mealPaging.nextStep()
      else this.mealPaging.previousStep()
  }
```

```
<div class="second-step-holder">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
            <div> <img class="img-icon" src="../../assets/questionnarie-meal/5.step/Ikona 5.svg" alt="icon">
            </div>
            <div>
                <h1 class="title">
                    Koliko časa si <br> vzamete za kuhanje <br> največjega obroka?
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="d-flex first-row width-500 ">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                    <label class="container">
                        <input class="input-form-abs" value="1" type="radio" name="meal" id="mela">
                        <span class="checkmark"> </span>
                        <p>10 min</p>
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                    <label class="container">
                        <input class="input-form-abs" value="2" type="radio" name="meal" id="second">
                        <span class="checkmark"> </span>
                        <p> 30 min</p>
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                    <label class="container">
                        <input class="input-form-abs" value="3" type="radio" name="meal" id="second">
                        <span class="checkmark"> </span>
                        <p> 1 euro ali vec </p>
                    </label>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<app-questionarie-buttons [valueData]="objectToSendMeal" (sendEvent)="receivedPage($event)"></app-questionarie-buttons>
```

**ALL code is here :**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-inputgubtotnw?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: its only add to the button `<button [disable]="!objectToSendMeal.perDay?true:null">`. See that you use the way `[disable]`=`(condition)? true :null`. you need use "null" to say Angular not include the tag "disable".NOTE: the condition to the second page can be (`!objectToSendMeal.timeForMeal.hourFirstMeal || !objectToSendMeal.timeForMeal.hourSecondMeal || !objectToSendMeal.timeForMeal.hourThirdMeal`, see that the `!` indicate if is false or empty. NOTE2 you can simply your code using arrays for the options and *ngFor